# return url cordova app

Tags: cordova, redirect, external-url

I want to go to a external page to do some actions and the it has to redirect to the page I indicate in the returnUrl. It works fine in the browser, but when I try it in the device it crashes.

```
window.location.href = "http://" + publicKey + ".externalURL/" + publicKey + "?token=" + data[0].token + "&returnUrl=http://localhost/htmlfileinapp.html/" + publicKey
```

Comment: localhost wont work in device. Please use your IP instead

Comment: That is the problem, I know it does not work in device. I want to redirect it to a html view included in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer : you cannot open an *inside app page.html* externally in the device browser. It is simply IMPOSSIBLE**.
You only can open it in the browser **inside** the app.

*Or put your page online...* It s a matter of app conception, not code.